# Stop PHP foreach $posts as $post

Tags: php, post, foreach

I am using  `<? foreach $posts as $post) ?>` to call out all my posts that are added to database. I actually want to call out 3 of the new added posts to database, not all 20.

How can I do that?
I have read most of the topics, but they didn't work as I tought.

Thank you!

Comment: Use a `LIMIT` clause in your query

Comment: Limit your data rather than your output, but with that being said, `array_slice` should work fine. Alternately, just add `1` to a number and `break` when the number is above `3`.

Comment: limit your query, or use a php-side counter and `break;`

Comment: I tried both, as from several posts, but they somehow made my posts disapear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query will do...

```
select * from posts order by id desc limit 3  //hoping posts is your table name
```

`order by id desc` will orde your posts in descending order

`limit 3` will fetch the first 3 data

after getting the data you can use `foreach` to display them

hope this helps...

Comment: Yes, this is working. Thank you. I forgot I could use the query.

Comment: Quick question, how you do it 2 times, if there are same querys from same table, but one shows 3 and other shows all on same page.

Comment: `$query= "select * from posts order by id desc";                    if(condition) $query.= "limit 3"` at starting limit to 3 if user wants to view all you can show all. the above `if` will do.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few methods to limit `$posts`, but if you can't modify that for some crazy reason, you can use:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    if ($i == 0) $post = current($posts);
    else $post = next($posts);
    // Do stuff with $post
}
```

Comment: What's the point of using `current` and `next`? Why not just use the `[]` operator?

Comment: @bali182 Keys are unknown

Answer (score 0):

Or if you cannot use the LIMIT clause, you can do

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    if ($i++ > 2) {
        break;
    }

    // do something with $post
}
```